# Using a TLD used for JSP in an XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, jsp, xslt

I am working on updating an XSLT transformation, and part of this update involves importing some functionality that is already in place in a JSP.

The functionality that is provided to the JSP is done so with a number of custom tags, that are described within a TLD (http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee:taglib) XML file, and the JSP file contains a line at the top: `<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/utilTags.tld" prefix="tags" %>`

Now, this XSLT requires some common functionality that is provided to the JSP from this library of custom tags.

I have tried inserting the line at the top: `xmlns:tags="/WEB-INF/tlds/utilTags.tld"`, but that didn't work (I didn't really expect it to). So, how can I import these tags into an XSLT transformation?

Answer (score 1):

XSLT engines can interpret and run XSLT syntax.

Taglibs have a different syntax and completely different runtime environment.

In theory it could be possible that a (Java) XSLT engine could integrate taglibs as *extension*, but I doubt that this has been done.

TLDR: it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT itself won't interpret JSP directives.  Instead you might do one of the following:

1. Run the JSP first, then match against its output using XSLT, *or*
2. Use JSP [transform](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97338_01/doc/jsp.106/devguide/xml.htm) directive to run XSLT within JSP:

**hello.jsp**

```
<%@ page session = "false" %>
<%@ taglib uri="oracle.jsp.parse.OpenJspRegisterLib" prefix="jml" %>

<jml:transform href="hello.xsl" >

  <page>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <content>
      <paragraph>This is my first XML/XSL file!</paragraph>
    </content>
  </page>

</jml:transform>
```

**hello.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="page">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </title>
      </head>
      <body bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title">
    <h1 align="center">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </h1>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="paragraph">
    <p align="center">
      <i>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </i>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Generates this HTML:**

```
<root>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<h1 align="center">Hello</h1>

<p align="center"><i>This is my first XML/XSL file!</i></p>

</body>
</html>
</root>
```